# bidi: Strange error tkz-tab package with texlive 2018

Tags: right-to-left, bidi

I have texlive 2018 on my pc and I'm facing issues with tkz-tab package which were not shown with texlive 2017

```
! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.136 \newinsert\@bidi@copyins@

?
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\begin{document}
أهلا
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tkz-tab loads `etex.sty`. If I prevent this the document compiles fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@etex.sty\endcsname{}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}

\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}

\begin{document}
أهلا
\end{document}
```